# HLS conversion issue while using "var_stream_map"

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, hls

I am using the following command to convert an existing .mp4 video into multiple video and audio formats

```
ffmpeg -y \
    -i sample.mp4 \
    -hls_list_size 0 \
    -hls_key_info_file keyfile \
    -b:v:0 1080k -b:v:1 720k -b:v:2 480k -b:v:3 240k -b:a:0 64k -b:a:1 32k \
    -map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:a \
    -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:0 v:2,a:0 v:3,a:1" \
    -master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
    "output/%v/manifest.m3u8"
```

Requirement is to convert the existing video into 4 qualities i.e., 1080k, 720k, 480k and 240k. Audio into two formats 64k and 32k.

Output expected is to have

1. video quality of 1080k and audio quality of 64k
2. video quality of 720k and audio quality of 64k
3. video quality of 480k and audio quality of 64k
4. video quality of 240k and audio quality of 32k

The command mentioned is creating a master playlist, with the following content

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1258400,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2"
0/manifest.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=862400,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2"
1/manifest.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=598400,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2"
2/manifest.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=299200,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2"
3/manifest.m3u8
```

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong ?

Also any documentations explaining the "-map" and "-var_stream_map" option would be much appreciated.

The [FFMPEG documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1)

has examples, but the explanation for these options is not very clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers 1080, 720, 480, 240 usually denote resolution and they are suffixed with `p`, not `k`. You have assigned these numbers to bitrate option, which won't rescale the streams.

Add `-filter:v:0 scale=-2:1080 -filter:v:1 scale=-2:720 -filter:v:2 scale=-2:480 -filter:v:3 scale=-2:240`.

You'll also want to replace the bitrate values e.g.

`-b:v:0 4000k -b:v:1 2000k -b:v:2 1000k -b:v:3 300k`

But the actual values will depend on your business requirements.

---

Your input audio is 6 channels. Web players typically want 2 channels. So add `-ac 2`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain a little more on the "-2" in the scale options. Also is the -map arguments right ?

Also, for some resolutions, the audio is not working. Is this caused due to "-map" option.

Comment: When is audio not working?

Comment: It is working only for the 240 resolution, rest all cases it does not work

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: [logs](https://pastebin.com/vdMdxG9Z)

Comment: Added audio arg.

Comment: Added the -ac argument, but still no luck. The issue persists

Comment: Add -report and run. Share report.

Comment: [Logs -1] (https://pastebin.com/xYm7Bc5x)
[Logs -2] (https://pastebin.com/t3QidwMK)

Comment: Map the audio once for each variant.

Comment: What should I change the `-map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:a 
    -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:0 v:2,a:0 v:3,a:1" ` to ?

Comment: `-map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:a -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2 v:3,a:3"`

Comment: And `-b:a:0 64k -b:a:1 32k` to `-b:a 64k -b:a:3 32k`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Works for me now. Can you point me to some docs which can help me reduce the initial .m3u8 file size ? The initial buffer time is too large